# MSVC Compiler Error C2688: Microsoft C++ ABI corner case issue?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, abi

A very specific corner case that MSVC disallows via [Compiler Error 2688](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34yfcksa.aspx) is [admitted by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9feath.aspx) to be non-standard behavior. Does anyone know why MSVC++ has this specific limitation?

The fact that it involves simultaneous usage of three language features ("virtual base classes", "covariant return types", and "variable number of arguments", according to the description in the second linked page) that are semantically orthogonal and fully supported separately seems to imply that this is not a parsing or semantic issue, but a corner case in the Microsoft C++ ABI. In particular, the fact that a "variable number of arguments" is involved seems to (?) suggest that the C++ ABI is using an implicit trailing parameter to implement the combination of the other two features, but can't because there's no fixed place to put that parameter when the function is var arg.

Does anyone have enough knowledge of the Microsoft C++ ABI to confirm whether this is the case, and explain what this implicit trailing argument is used for (or what else is going on, if my guess is incorrect)? The C++ ABI is not documented by Microsoft but I know that some people outside of Microsoft have done work to match the ABI for various reasons so I'm hoping someone can explain what is going on.

Also, Microsoft's documentation is a bit inconsistent; the second page linked says:

> Virtual base classes are not supported as covariant return types when the virtual function has a variable number of arguments.

but the first page more broadly states:

> covariant returns with **multiple or** virtual inheritance not supported for varargs functions

Does anyone know what the real story is? I can do some experimentation to find out, but I'm guessing that the actual corner case is neither of these, exactly, but has to do with the specifics of the class hierachy in a way that the documenters decided to gloss over. My guess it that it has to do with the need for a pointer adjustment in the virtual thunk, but I'm hoping someone with deeper knowledge of the situation than me can explain what's going on behind the hood.

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you with authority that MSVC's C++ ABI uses implicit extra parameters to do things that in other ABIs (namely Itanium) implement multiple separate functions to handle, so it's not hard to imagine that one is being used here (or would be, if the case were supported).

I don't know for sure what's happening in this case, but it seems plausible that an implicit extra parameter is being passed to tell the thunk implementing the virtual function whether a downcast to the covariant return type class is required (or, more likely, whether an upcast back to the base class is required, since the actual implementing function probably returns the derived class), and that this extra parameter goes last so that it can be ignored by the base classes (which wouldn't know anything about the covariant return).

This implies that the unsupported corner case occurs always when a virtual base class is the original return type (since a thunk will always be required to the derived class) which is what is described in the first quote; it would also happen in some, but not all, cases involving multiple inheritance (which may be why it's included in the second quote, but not the first).